# Gradle creates war with servlet-api 2.5 instead of 3.0.1

Tags: java, jetty, gradle, war

I'm using Gradle 1.9 (extra details below) to build a WAR that will run over Jetty 9 (jetty-9.0.5.v20130815).

It is configured in `web.xml` -

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
...
```

build.gradle has this dependency -

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.26'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3'
    compile 'commons-pool:commons-pool:1.6'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}
```

building using `gradle clean war` produces a WAR file with `servlet-api-2.5.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib/`.

More env details -

```
Build time:   2013-11-19 08:20:02 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     7970ec3503b4f5767ee1c1c69f8b4186c4763e3d

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9 x86_64
```

The webapp seem to work without `servlet-api-2.5.jar` (deleted it manually), but I haven't checked all functionality available.

Is it a dependency of other library?
Is this a bad thing?

Comment: Does your `WEB-INF/web.xml` specify servlet api 2.5? or 3.0?

Comment: Yes, added the config to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run dependencies report to see which library pulls in servlet-api-2.5:

```
gradle dependencies --configuration runtime
```

Once you know which library pulls in servlet-api-2.5, you have two options:

Disable transitive dependencies for the library:

```
runtime('org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5') {
   transitive = false
}
runtime group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate', version: '3.0.5', transitive: false
```

Exclude a particular transitive dependency:

```
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate:3.1') {
  //excluding a particular transitive dependency:
  exclude module: 'cglib' //by artifact name
  exclude group: 'org.jmock' //by group
  exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'iAmBuggy' //by both name and group
}
```

If you wonder, why this conflict was not resolved by Gradle automatically, it is because 2.5 and 3.0 have different names:

```
javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
```

Hope it helps.

**Update:**

I looked at 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2', it depends on 'javax.servlet:jsp-api:2.0', which depends on 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.4'

Comment: The dependencies report made the breakthrough. Turns out that one of my subprojects had this dependency, once removed problem resolved. Thanks!

Comment: What confused me a lot is the fact that if gradle pulls in depedencies via some other (and older) library reference, the dependencies still show for the newest library version, although that might be the one that you explicitly declared as transitive:false

Answer (score 5):

In more recent versions of gradle you can make use of [module replacement](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:module_replacement):

```
dependencies {
    modules {
        module("javax.servlet:servlet-api") {
            replacedBy("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api")
        }
    }
}
```